# How to consume other application webservice from MSDynamics CRM?

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm

We want to integrate our site with MSDynamics CRM.To get data from our site to MSDynamics CRM,we want to call webservice of our site from MSDynamics CRM.How could we do this?We would be grateful if provided some example codes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this May be helpful:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa613627.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150838.aspx
use the link above may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think create a web service that your site refer and using the Dynamics CRM sdk to do operation to CRM.

Example:

WCF

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IService1
 {
      [OperationContract]
      Guid CreateContact(String firstname, String lastname, String email);
 }
```

Implementation using CRM SDK

```
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        readonly IOrganizationService _service = new OrganizationService("CRMConnectionStringName");

        public Guid CreateContact(string firstname, string lastname, string email)
        {
            var contact = new Entity("contact");
            contact.Attributes["firstname"] = firstname;
            contact.Attributes["lastname"] = lastname;
            contact.Attributes["emailaddress1"] = email;

            var contactId = _service.Create(contact);

            return contactId;
        }
    }
```